# Renaming a class variable not reflected in JSON output

Tags: java, json, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm doing a web service with Spring MVC in Eclipse that reads data from a database and dumps it as JSON. I recently added a new variable in class that's used to hold a row from a table in the database, for example:

```
public class DbRow {
  private Integer Id;
  private String  Label;
  ...
  public String getLabel() {
    return Label;
  }
  public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.Label = label;
  }
}
```

However, as later the name of the column in the database changed, I reflected this by renaming the class variable (with Refactor -> Rename... or Alt + Shift + R in Eclipse) as well as its getter and setter methods like this:

```
public class DbRow {
  private Integer Id;
  private String  Title;
  ...
  public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
  }
  public void setLabel(String title) {
    this.Title = title;
  }
}
```

And my problem now is that in the JSON output of the service the field is still with it's old name like this

```
{"Id":"100","Label":"Test"}
```

instead of

```
{"Id":"100","Title":"Test"}
```

This breaks my mockMvc test that I run with TestNG in Eclipse (e.g. error org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Fields with the following paths were not found in the payload: [Title]).

How could I fix this?

Comment: Method `setLabel(String title)` has not been refactored may be.

Comment: are you sure about the renaming of getter and setter ?

Comment: It was the getter in fact, I mixed the example.

Answer (score 0):

your setter method is still old

`public void setLabel(String title) {
    this.Title = title;
  }`

update it with `setTitle(String title)`. Moreover, try to clean-build project and run your testcases afterwards.

Comment: In fact, I've done an error in the example, but in the real code it was the getter that wasn't renamed, so this was the real problem. Nice suggestion indeed :-) Thanks.

Comment: I should have used 'Rename getter' and 'Rename setter' in Rename Field dialog to automatically refactor the names of getter and setter together with the field.